# Incorrect result with TransparentBlt

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I am working on a transparent treeview control. In order to achieve transparency I have subclassed the tree and am overriding `WM_PAINT` ( in my `WM_ERASEBKGND` handler I just return `TRUE`. Scrolling, mousewheel and other relevant messages are handled properly ). 
To make tree’s background transparent I am using the following algorithm ( based on [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/misc-advanced/article.php/c679/Using-a-bitmap-as-a-background-image.htm) *CodeGuru* article ):

1. Let tree do its default painting in memory DC ( saved in `memDC` ).
2. Get parent’s background in another memory DC ( saved in `finalDC` ).
3. Map tree’s and parent’s coordinates so I can grab correct portion of parent’s background bitmap.
4. Combine these two images using `TransparentBlt` and tree’s background color ( `TransparentBlt( finalDC, ... , memDC, ... );` ).

---

In parent window I have implemented `WM_PRINTCLIENT`, so I can copy its background into memory DC ( step 2 ) with a simple `::SendMessage( GetParent(hwnd), WM_PRINTCLIENT, (WPARAM)finalDC, (LPARAM)(PRF_CLIENT) );` call. The result I get is correct both on *Windows XP* and *Windows7* :

[image]

---

I obtain tree’s default bitmap ( step 1 ) with `::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)memDC, 0 );` call. Here too, the result is correct both on *Windows XP* and *Windows7*:

On *Windows XP* ( I do not know why uploaded image misses checkboxes, everything looks fine on my computer ) :

[image]

On *Windows7* ( I do not know why uploaded image misses checkboxes, everything looks fine on my computer ) :

[image]

---

However, after `TransparentBlt()` call, final picture is not drawn properly:

On *Windows XP* checkboxes are the problem -> [image]

On *Windows7* some white is left in letters -> [image]

---

These pictures are result of exporting bitmaps from device contexts into file ( I have modified [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to achieve that ).

Here is the code snippet for `WM_PAINT`:

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // usual stuff
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;

        RECT rcClient = {0};
        GetClientRect( hwnd, &rcClient );

        HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

        // create helper memory DCs 
        HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc), finalDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

        // create helper bitmaps
        HBITMAP memBmp,  // default tree's paint
            finalBmp,    // parent's background image
            bmpOld, bmpOldFinal;  // needed for cleanup

        memBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, 
            rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
            rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top );

        bmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( memDC, memBmp );

        // map parent and child rectangles

        RECT rcParent; 
        GetClientRect( GetParent(hwnd), &rcParent );

        // upper left corners of the treeview, parent window
        POINT ptTreeUL, ptParentUL; 

        // map tree's coordinates
        ptTreeUL.x = rcClient.left;
        ptTreeUL.y = rcClient.top;

        ClientToScreen( hwnd, &ptTreeUL );

        // map parent's coordinates
        ptParentUL.x = rcParent.left;
        ptParentUL.y = rcParent.top;

        ScreenToClient( GetParent(hwnd), &ptParentUL );

        /********* get parent's background image *******/

        finalBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, 
            rcParent.right - rcParent.left,
            rcParent.bottom - rcParent.top );

        bmpOldFinal = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( finalDC, finalBmp );

        ::SendMessage( GetParent(hwnd), WM_PRINTCLIENT,(WPARAM)finalDC, 
            (LPARAM)(PRF_CLIENT) );

        /********* capture default tree image *********/

        ::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, WM_PAINT, (WPARAM)memDC, 0 );

        // get tree's background color 

        COLORREF clrMask = TreeView_GetBkColor(hwnd);

        if( clrMask == -1 )  // this means tree uses default system color
            clrMask = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);

        /**** combine tree's default image with parent's background ****/
        /**** so we can erase default background with parent's background ****/

        TransparentBlt( finalDC, 
            ptParentUL.x + ptTreeUL.x, 
            ptParentUL.y + ptTreeUL.y, 
            rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
            rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
            memDC, 
            0, 0, 
            rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
            rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
            clrMask );

        // draw the result into tree's DC
        BitBlt( hdc, 
            0, 0, 
            rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
            rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
            finalDC, 
            ptParentUL.x + ptTreeUL.x, 
            ptParentUL.y + ptTreeUL.y, SRCCOPY);

        // cleanup
        SelectObject( memDC, bmpOld );
        DeleteDC( memDC );
        DeleteObject( memBmp );
        SelectObject( finalDC, bmpOldFinal );
        DeleteDC( finalDC );
        DeleteObject( finalBmp );

        EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
    }
    return 0L;
```

How can I properly combine default tree bitmap with parent’s background, achieving transparency without visual artifacts ?

### EDIT:

I was able to fix checkbox issue by ditching `TransparentBlt()` and doing things myself.

*ClearType font* is still a problem, artifacts remained. Mask creation is the problem. As member *arx* said, background combining is responsible for that. If I could create proper mask then my problem would be solved.

Here is the entire subclass procedure :

```
LRESULT CALLBACK TreeProc( HWND hwnd, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, 
    UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData )
{
    switch (message)
    {
    // handle messages that paint tree without WM_PAINT
    case WM_TIMER:  // handles autoscrolling when item is partially visible
    case TVM_DELETEITEM:
    case TVM_INSERTITEM: 
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL: 
    case WM_HSCROLL:  
    case WM_VSCROLL:  
        {
            ::SendMessage( hwnd, WM_SETREDRAW, (WPARAM)FALSE, 0 );

            LRESULT lres = ::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );

            ::SendMessage( hwnd, WM_SETREDRAW, (WPARAM)TRUE, 0 );

            ::RedrawWindow( hwnd, NULL, NULL, 
                RDW_FRAME | RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW );

            return lres;
        }
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            // usual stuff

            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwnd, &ps );

            // get client coordinates of parent and tree window

            RECT rcClient = {0}, rcParent = {0};

            GetClientRect( hwnd, &rcClient );
            GetClientRect( GetParent(hwnd), &rcParent );

            // create helper DCs and bitmaps

            HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc),    //default tree paint
                finalDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc),  // parent's WM_PRINTCLIENT
                maskDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);   // DC that holds monochrome mask

            HBITMAP memBmp,  // default tree's paint
                finalBmp,    // parent's background image
                maskBmp,      // monochrome mask
                bmpOld, bmpOldFinal, bmpOldMask;  // needed for cleanup

            memBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
                rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top );

            bmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( memDC, memBmp );

            /****** get parent's background image *******/

            finalBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, rcParent.right - rcParent.left,
                rcParent.bottom - rcParent.top );

            bmpOldFinal = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( finalDC, finalBmp );

            ::SendMessage( GetParent(hwnd), WM_PRINTCLIENT,(WPARAM)finalDC,
                (LPARAM)(PRF_CLIENT) );

            /****** capture default tree image *********/

            ::SendMessage( hwnd, WM_PRINTCLIENT,(WPARAM)memDC, (LPARAM)(PRF_CLIENT) );

            /********** create monochrome mask *******/

            // get tree's background color 

            COLORREF clrMask = TreeView_GetBkColor(hwnd);

            if( clrMask == -1 )
                clrMask = ::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);

            maskBmp = CreateBitmap( rcClient.right - rcClient.left,
               rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, 1, 1, NULL );

            bmpOldMask = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( maskDC, maskBmp );

            SetBkColor( memDC, clrMask ); // this color becomes white, all others black

            BitBlt( maskDC, 0, 0, rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
                rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY );

            /***** map tree's coordinates to parent window *****/

            POINT ptTreeUL;

            ptTreeUL.x = rcClient.left;
            ptTreeUL.y = rcClient.top;

            ClientToScreen( hwnd, &ptTreeUL );
            ScreenToClient( GetParent(hwnd), &ptTreeUL );

            /***** creating transparent background ********/

            // mask the original image

            SetBkColor( memDC, RGB( 0, 0, 0 ) ); 
            SetTextColor( memDC, RGB( 255, 255, 255 ) );

            BitBlt( memDC, 0, 0, 
                rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
                rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                maskDC, 0, 0, SRCAND );

            // create transparent treeview image 

            SetBkColor( finalDC, RGB ( 255, 255, 255 ) ); 
            SetTextColor( finalDC, RGB ( 0, 0, 0 ) );

            BitBlt( finalDC, ptTreeUL.x, ptTreeUL.y, 
                rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
                rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                maskDC, 0, 0, SRCAND );

            BitBlt( finalDC, ptTreeUL.x, ptTreeUL.y, 
                rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
                rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                memDC, 0, 0, SRCPAINT );

            // display the result 

            BitBlt( hdc, 0, 0, 
                rcClient.right - rcClient.left, 
                rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top,
                finalDC, ptTreeUL.x, ptTreeUL.y, SRCCOPY );

            /***************** cleanup ******************/

            SelectObject( memDC, bmpOld );
            DeleteDC( memDC );
            DeleteObject( memBmp );

            SelectObject( finalDC, bmpOldFinal );
            DeleteDC( finalDC );
            DeleteObject( finalBmp );

            SelectObject( maskDC, bmpOldMask );
            DeleteDC( maskDC );
            DeleteObject( maskBmp );

            EndPaint( hwnd, &ps );
        }
        return 0L;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_NCDESTROY:
        ::RemoveWindowSubclass( hwnd, TreeProc, 0 );
        return ::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return ::DefSubclassProc( hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

In parent window draw the image from `WM_PAINT` in response to [`WM_PRINTCLIENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( remember to use `(HDC)wParam` instead of `BeginPaint`, and to `return (LRESULT)0;` ). I drew a gradient as can be seen on the pictures above.

In parent window you must add the following in your `WM_NOTIFY` handler:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        if( ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_SELCHANGING )
        {
            InvalidateRect( ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom, NULL, FALSE );
            break;
        }

        if( ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDING )
        {
            InvalidateRect( ((LPNMHDR)lParam)->hwndFrom, NULL, FALSE );
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
```

Only font remains to be fixed.

### END OF EDIT

Comment: If you are still in trouble, I have some code that might help you without changing much of your code, but then I would need you to provide some code of your own (to reproduce this problem). It would be done by manually manipulating bitmaps. I could just post it to do it yourself, but my code is currently being rewritten and some functions are still unavailable, so I will have to write function for you specifically.

Comment: @Helix: I have made a progress regarding checkboxes, but ClearType font is killing me. It is the only thing left... After researching  a little I start to fear that fixing it is impossible. Still, I could post the entire subclass procedure or even better, a small SSCCE project if you are interested? Thank you for offering help, I appreciate it as always.

Comment: Well, I am interested in fixing your code so if you could post it, it would be great.

Comment: @Helix: I have edited my post with subclass procedure. Do not forget to add stuff for `WM_NOTIFY` when testing and pay attention to `WM_PRINTCLIENT` ( I do not know if you used this message before so I must warn you ). Hopefully you will be able to figure something out. Best regards until then.

Comment: It is actually nearly impossible, it seem that you will need to draw text yourself :/

Comment: @Helix: I was able to create font that uses standard antialiasing with `CreateFont`, read description of all parameters carefully. Once I set it to be tree's font everything works fine. For now this will have to do, but the fight is not over yet! Thank you for trying. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows 7 the text is smoothed with anti-aliasing.  Windows doesn't paint pixels of black text on a background of solid colour, it paints a blend between black and the background colour.

`TransparentBlt` treats a single solid colour as transparent.  Hence it doesn't treat the antialiased edges of the text as transparent, so these edges are visible in the final bitmap.

To fix this you could select a font with anti-aliasing disabled, but obviously this will give you more lumpy text.

The problem on XP is that the corner of the check-boxes is the same colour as the background.  You can probably fix this by changing the background to a colour that doesn't clash (e.g. magenta).

Comment: You won't like this, but there is no easy solution to this problem. The only way to ensure no rendering artifacts is to do all the drawing yourself (using custom draw), and even then there are a ton of kludges you will need to fix everything. I should know, I've done it myself - and with hindsight it would have been easier to write my own tree control.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: What do you mean "write my own tree control" ? I would be interested to try this approach but do not know what are you referring to. Can you provide an article/code example/tutorial that can help me out ?

Comment: I mean implement your own control that mimics the one the shell provides. It would be a reasonable amount of work although you wouldn't necessarily need to implement all its features, only those you actually need. Whether this approach is worth it or not is up to you - it IS possible to get transparency working with the system control using a combination of custom draw, sub-classing and a lot of glue and sticky tape.

Comment: Those custom controls are an illusion, all you need to do is to track mouse movement in your own window's "button" area and paint accordingly to user actions (click, leave, hover and so on). For painting you might want to write your own drawing code (that's what I am doing and it's the hardest part), because some parts might make you mad. With custom drawing code you will get easy blending and transparency options. If you are willing to wait, after 2 months I plan to finish rewriting custom control template and I think I'll be willing to share.

Comment: @Helix: Thank you. I will try to fix `ClearType` font issue since this is the only thing left for me to solve. After ditching `TransparentBlt` and doing manual transparency checkbox issue disappeared. If only I could fix the font my problem would be solved! The problem is in *mask bitmap* -> antialiasing "tricks" it for the source background color. When I blit the source into monochrome DC text background is not converted into appropriate color because it is combined, as member *arx* pointed out. If I could somehow create proper mask everything would be solved...

Comment: Just post your code sample (with checkbox and cleartype) and tomorrow (after ~16 hours or so) I will adapt it to my drawing code which will give you more freedom and there will be no need for mask bitmaps and so on. You might wonder why I help you, but it's just in my nature.