# How to remove green screen from bmp in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, image-processing, direct2d

so i am new to Direct2D and image processing world, and kind of lost right now. I have this image with green background, that i need to load. But green background must be removed before displaying it to the screen(using c++ chroma key).

So far, i have been successful in loading d2d bitmap from a jpg/bmp file onto screen. Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but i couldn't find much information anywhere else. Here's the image that i'm trying to process.

So the steps that i used to load bitmap are, creating WIC factory, creating decoder to be able to read file into WIC, create converter for WIC and configuring it.

The final step was to create bitmap.

Then i draw it on screen with `RendetTarget->DrawBitmap()` method passing appropriate parameters.

The only thing i can't figure out right now is how to remove green screen from the image below. Let me know if my question is lacking some necessary information. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's code to drawing bitmap on the screen

```
gfx->GetRenderTarget()->DrawBitmap(
    bmp, //Bitmap we built from WIC
    D2D1::RectF(0, 0,
        bmp->GetSize().width, bmp->GetSize().height), 
    0.8f, // opacity
D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR,

    D2D1::RectF(0, 0, bmp->GetSize().width, bmp->GetSize().height) //Source Rect
    );
```

[image: ! [Planet_Image]

Here's the screenshot of my executable (window) and what i've so far.
[Main Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj1K3.png)

Here's the code loading bitmaps

```
this->gfx = gfx;
bmp = NULL; 
HRESULT hr;


IWICImagingFactory *wicFactory = NULL;

hr = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
    NULL, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IWICImagingFactory, 

    (LPVOID*)&wicFactory); // pointer to the WICFactory

// decoder
IWICBitmapDecoder *wicDecoder = NULL;
hr = wicFactory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
    filename, // filename passed as parameter
    NULL, 
    GENERIC_READ, 
    WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, 
    &wicDecoder); // pointer to the Decoder 


IWICBitmapFrameDecode* wicFrame = NULL;
hr = wicDecoder->GetFrame(0, &wicFrame); 


// create wic converter
IWICFormatConverter *wicConverter = NULL;

hr = wicFactory->CreateFormatConverter(&wicConverter);


hr = wicConverter->Initialize(
    wicFrame, 
    GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, 
    WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, 
    NULL, 
    0.0, 
    WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom 
    );


// create bitmap
gfx->GetRenderTarget()->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(
    wicConverter, 
    NULL, 
    &bmp // destination bmp defined in header
);
```

Comment: No idea, really, but I did a search and found this: "The green (or magenta) is what the debug D3D runtime will clear your surface to with certatin swap modes to indicate that the contents of that surface are undefined. With the retail D3D runtime, "undefined" means that the surface could easily be full of garbage, or whatever the last app rendered to it etc..." https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/184717-direct3d-background-color/

Comment: In other words, it would seem to indicate that there is just nothing there, because you didn't put anything there.

Comment: So basically, it would replace green pixel with nothing? Hence, removing all the green?

Comment: _"c++ chroma key"_ o.O

Comment: What did you expect to see instead of the green? Analyse the answer to that question and all will be revealed.

Comment: I just want to see the planet. No background. Maybe make all green pixels transparent would be one of solution, if not the best one.

Comment: But issue here is, how do iterate through all the pixels? And what should i compare them to, i mean there are so many shades of green, how do i know which one it is? Cause for us, different shades of green is still green, but for computer, it is entirely different color, isn't it? And how do i change pixel color to transparent?

Comment: We would need to see more code. Is this Direct2D render target directly on your top-level window or on a child window?

Comment: @andlabs It's on top-level window. Actually there's just one window where i have 3 planets and a moving triangle. I have just updated my question with my actual window screenshot, please take a look.

Comment: And do the source images have transparency?

Comment: Nope they have no transparency. Absolutely opaque.

Comment: Hence i had to draw the background (which is space) first, followed by planets and triangle. Else planets won't be visible if space.jpg had overlapped it.

Comment: You can make the green part transparent but the image won't look very good. That circle has a smooth circumference, that's due to anti-aliasing. You would still see a faint green circumference. Use PNG image with multi-layer transparency instead. I am voting to close because you haven't shown the relevant code.

Comment: I will say that these BMPs with a solid color background are specifically what `TransparentBlt()` was made to handle, but since you are using WIC with Direct2D and not GDI I wouldn't know how that information would help you other than to get the correct terminology to find an equivalent. And again, this is really only good for images that are either fully transparent or fully opaque; as @BarmakShemirani says, you'll need to find the original PNGs if you want true transparency with proper antialiasing.

Comment: (The good news is that [WIC *should* be able to handle PNGs out of the box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654(v=vs.85).aspx)...)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Could you please tell how to make green part transparent, i know it's not the best solution, as you said we'll still see faint green on circumference, but it'll still be helpful. :)

Comment: @Shrey Ideally you should post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least show the part of the code for painting. See this example for [TransparentBlt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432110/incorrect-result-with-transparentblt)

Comment: You're right, i should've posted code. But the only reason i did not was because i had no clue how to approach this issue. The code i had so far deals with creating a green triangle, loading .bmps onto display. I did not have anything that i could have posted on removing green screen issue. I have scoured the internet for solutions but could not find a good starting point for this, hence i posted over here. I understand it is unprofessional to post without trying, and i will make sure it doesn't happen in future. It's just that i could not figure out how to start about this. Thanks though :)

Comment: You clearly have some code which draws bitmaps and a triangle. Just post it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani  I just updated the question with code. Please take a look. Also there's an image to final output window i'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will draw a background and sprite with transparency on top of it. All you have to do is load a png file with transparency. Use an image editor to convert the bitmap to png. This requires Visual Studio Atl COM classes `CComPtr`, but you can do it without that.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <Wincodec.h>

HRESULT load_image(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *target, 
    const wchar_t *filename, ID2D1Bitmap** bitmap)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_FALSE;
    CComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> factory;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
    CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> frame;
    CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> converter;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, 
        NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWICImagingFactory, (void**)&factory);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = factory->CreateDecoderFromFilename(filename, NULL, 
        GENERIC_READ, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &decoder);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = decoder->GetFrame(0, &frame);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = factory->CreateFormatConverter(&converter);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = converter->Initialize(frame, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, 
        WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = target->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(converter, 0, bitmap);
    return hr;
}

void on_render(ID2D1HwndRenderTarget *render)
{
    render->BeginDraw();
    render->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));

    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> background;
    if SUCCEEDED(load_image(render, L"c:\\background.jpg", &background))
    {
        D2D1_SIZE_F size = background->GetSize();
        render->DrawBitmap(background, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    }

    CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> sprite;
    if SUCCEEDED(load_image(render, L"c:\\transparent.png", &sprite))
    {
        D2D1_SIZE_F size = sprite->GetSize();
        render->DrawBitmap(sprite, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    }

    render->EndDraw();
}
```

`TransparentBlt` is a GDI function and can only handle single transparency. If you are going to use GDI functions then maybe you don't need the complexity of Direct2D! Alternatively you can use GDI+

```
if(msg == WM_PAINT)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    auto hbitmap = LoadImage(NULL, L"test.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    auto memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    int w = bm.bmWidth;
    int h = bm.bmHeight;
    TransparentBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc, 0, 0, w, h, RGB(0, 255, 0));

    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
    DeleteObject(hbitmap);//<- edit
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @BarkmakShemirani, this code helped a lot. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I had an error in the second part, it should be `DeleteObject(hbitmap)` as shown in edit